# 2D mapping of PDB Layout in Allegro

Tags: pcb-design, pcb-assembly, allegro

I am trying to export a 2D drawing of my pcb layout in allegro. I would like the layout to include the components and their reference designators. However, I cannot find a way to do so and the exported pdf looks like this:
[image]

Instead, I am looking for a way to export the pdf showing the 3D models of the components and their names. If someone knows a way it would be really helpful.